# Property 'children' is missing in type '{ image: string; amount: number; }' but required in type 'BannerLayer'. TS2741

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Currently, I've face an error while using a library called React-Scroll-Parallax. It had no problem with JS but TS kept saying to me like as follows:

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { ParallaxProvider, ParallaxBanner } from 'react-scroll-parallax';
import styled from 'styled-components';

interface SubBannerProps {
  height?: string;
  style?: any;
  backgroundImage?: any;
}

const Wrapper = styled.div<SubBannerProps>`
  margin: 800px 0;
`;

const SubBanner: React.FC<SubBannerProps> = ({ height }) => {
  return (
    <Wrapper height={height}>
      <ParallaxProvider>
        <ParallaxBanner
          layers={[
            { image: 'assets/images/main-image.png',
              amount: 0.5,
            },
          ]}
          style={{
            height: '300px',
          }}
        />
      </ParallaxProvider>
    </Wrapper>
  );
};

export default SubBanner;
```

It seems this library doesn't support the current TS, so how to solve the problem??
I need to use it with TS.

```
Property 'children' is missing in type '{ image: string; amount: number; }' but required in type 'BannerLayer'.ts(2741)
```

Comment: Where is the `BannerLayer`?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The issue comes from `react-scroll-parallax` typings, it has been fixed with [`v2.3.3`](https://github.com/jscottsmith/react-scroll-parallax/releases/tag/v2.3.3).

Answer (score 0):

Usually this error is thrown when you try to use the `children` in the React component that not allows this explicitely (not exposing the `children` prop).

```
interface IComponentProps {
   image:string;
   amount:number;
}

<Component image="image" amount={1}>
  <p>This will throw</p>
</Component>
```

but if you will add it to the props (type) then it will accept it

```
interface IComponentProps {

   image:string;
   amount:number;

  children: ReactNode;
}
```